# Getting Yellow Bar advertisements in Office 2016 for Free Trial of Office 365

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2016

I am getting yellow bar ads now displaying in my licensed Office 2016 Home and Business products- notably Word 2016 and Outlook 2016. I do not use Office 365. The ads were occurring once a month, but now seem to be occurring more frequently. I cannot find anything on the web about how to turn them off. If anyone has any ideas - I would greatly appreciate it. [Recent example I got in Outlook 2016](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwITj.png)

[Privacy Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8QlO.png)

[Privacy Settings 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDwRj.png)

[Privacy Settings 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKooC.png)

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_install-mso_windows8/how-do-i-turn-off-the-get-the-new-office-ad/6ec18b27-42b3-4c54-8e6a-b9732922d3b0

Comment: The article referenced is for Office 365. Article says "If you're still using Office 2013 with your Microsoft 365 subscription, you'll eventually receive notifications to upgrade to Office 2016." To be clear, I am not using office 365. This is a standalone copy of Office 2016.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The ads were occurring once a month, but now seem to be occurring more frequently. I cannot find anything on the web about how to turn them off. If anyone has any ideas

You have to disable `Optional Connected Experiences` which can be found in the `Options` section within `Trust Center`.

**Optional Connected Experiences** must be disabled, this option can be found within **Privacy Options -> Privacy Settings**.

> [image]

> [image]

> [image]

Source: [How do I disable advertising in Outlook 2019?](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/86974/how-do-i-disable-advertising-in-outlook-2019.html)

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the information. Unfortunately, that box is unchecked in my settings. All of the options on that settings page are unchecked.

Comment: Please update your question with the appropriate screenshots in that case.

Comment: Posted my settings. It has been a few days since i got one of these. Will update when I see again.

Comment: That was the solution. I have not seen any more of these messages. Thanks for the help!